# HAProxy redirect to backend based on Sec-WebSocket-Protocol

Tags: websocket, protocols, haproxy

I want to create a rule that redirects traffic based on the WebSocket protocol.
eg So in javascript I might create a socket like this:

```
gstSocket = new WebSocket(url, proto);
```

I need HAProxy to detect the protocol specified.
e.g. :

```
acl detect_proto_rule hdr(Sec-WebSocket-Protocol) -i proto
use_backend proto_backend if detect_proto_rule
```

I don't know the correct way to write such a rule.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should delete this post but the correct format for such a rule was:
acl ws_valid_protocol hdr(Sec-WebSocket-Protocol) proto
source: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/websockets-load-balancing-with-haproxy/